# Mutating clone of object is mutating the original object prop passed down from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a parent component which passes an array of data to a child, that child then selects an object from the array, clones it, mutates it and sets it to state.

The problem I'm having is that when I mutate the clone, it's actually mutating the object inside the array prop as well. It seems that it's not actually being cloned but is still being used as a reference.

I'm currently using React 16.7.0a but I doubt that has anything to do with it.

```
const dummyDomain = { ...domains[domains.length - 1] }
const newDomain = Object.assign({}, dummyDomain)
newDomain.basics.name = 'please dont change the original object'
```

The code above runs when the child component mounts, and when it does and I go inspect the parent component with react dev tools, the original object in the array has been mutated.

[image: original object from parent component being mutated still]

I've never had this problem with React before which is why I've brought up the fact that I'm using React 16.7.0a. It's clear that I'm not directly referencing the object but actually creating a new one, so what gives?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple of ways of dealing with this. The not pulling in third party libraries approach is to use an Object deep copy.

```
const newDomain = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dummyDomain));
```

Otherwise you can go down the rabbit hole of moving immutable data to something like immutable.js (which does this kind of stuff behind the scenes).